# Redirect from /products/.* to /products not working

Tags: redirect, routing

Currently we have a route called `/products`. On this route there is a SPA active which handles the routes after `/products`. To ensure that people don't get a 404 when directly typing in a route like `/products/product-01` (because that page officially doesn't exist in Craft). We've setup a redirect (.htaccess) from `/products/.*` back to `/products` where the application handles the routing.

In Craft this seem to not work and give a 404. In case we make the base url `/en/products` a level deeper, there is no issue. So for example `www.domain.com/en/products/products-01` doesn't give this issue while `www.domain.com/products/products-01` does.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Sounds like your redirect rule might just be incorrect. Can you post the `.htaccess` rule? Also, what's the base URL of your site in the settings? Is `en` the primary site?

Comment: @MoritzLost see below

```RewriteRule ^products/.* /products [L]```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding custom routes to our Craft CMS install instead of using the .htaccess. Actually a better solution since we do not need .htaccess